# Editing a string where specific text is present and printing the result, and converting it to an array / Python3

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

beginner with python here.

How can I remove the ab that are next to eachother, and print out the result? 
As a beginner, I don't understand the terminology required in this, but i'd like it to be an infinite loop. Where can I look at that can put me in the right direction?

for example :

> string = "abcdabdad"

to remove all instances where this a and b [ab] are together, then print out the ultimate result.

I've written

```
string = "abcdabdad"
print("--" + string.replace("ab",""))
```

but this doesn't seem to work or be infinite. Any idea how to 1. Make it infinite and 2. convert the result to an array?

Comment: *"this doesn't seem to work or be infinite"* what do you mean with *be infinite*? It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: What is the outcome you'd expect? I've tried it and it printed `--cddad` which seems correct to me.